# How do you write a generic function to do conditional downcasting in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, functional-programming

My goal is to write something that can convert something like `[AnyObject]` to `Result<[SomeObject], NSError>` to easily do safe and chainable casting while working with a mixed Swift/Obj-C codebase. The conditional downcast operator `as?` seems to support that just fine, but I can't get a generic function working that utilizes that behavior. I've simplified the problem I'm encountering below:

```
class A { }

let obj = A()

let array: [AnyObject] = [obj]

func cast<T, U>(x: T, type: U.Type) -> U? {
    if let x = x as? U {
        return x
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

// This works
if let array = array as? [A] {
    println(array)
}

// This works
println(cast(obj, A.self))

// This doesn't
println(cast(array, [A].self))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, Swift doesn't support `GenericType<A> as? GenericType<B>` cast, even if `B` is a subtype of `A`. `Array<A> as? Array<B>` is just a exception for our convenience.

There is a *undocumented* internal builtin function:

```
func _arrayConditionalDownCastElements<SourceElement, TargetElement>(a: Array<SourceElement>) -> [TargetElement]?
```

With my assumption, Swift implicitly calls this function when we do `someArray as? [B]`. But, with a generics type, just like your case, the Swift compiler cannot bind that to `_arrayConditionalDownCastElements` because it's unpredictable in compile time.

Anyway, you can call it manually, and implement `cast` as overloaded function:

```
func cast<T,U>(x:T, _: U.Type) -> U? {
    return x as? U
}

func cast<T,U>(x:[T], _: [U].Type) -> [U]? {
   return _arrayConditionalCast(x)
}
```

Similarly, there is `_dictionaryDownCastConditional` for `Dictionary` and `_setDownCastConditional` for `Set`:

```
func _dictionaryDownCastConditional<BaseKey, BaseValue, DerivedKey, DerivedValue>(source: Dictionary<BaseKey, BaseValue>) -> Dictionary<DerivedKey, DerivedValue>?
func _setDownCastConditional<BaseValue, DerivedValue>(source: Set<BaseValue>) -> Set<DerivedValue>?
```

Using this:

```
func cast<TKey,TValue, UKey, UValue>(x:[TKey: TValue], _: [UKey:UValue].Type) -> [UKey: UValue]? {
    return _dictionaryDownCastConditional(x)
}

func cast<T, U>(x: Set<T>, _: Set<U>.Type) -> Set<U>? {
    return _setDownCastConditional(x)
}
```

Again, they are **undocumented**. use them at your own risk :)

Answer (score 2):

Note: This works in Swift 2.0, I don't know about 1.2, try it out

If you want to do something like this you'd have to overload your `cast` method with one for `SequenceType`s:

```
func cast<T : SequenceType, U : SequenceType>(x: T, type: U.Type) -> [U.Generator.Element]? {
    let y = x.map{ $0 as? U.Generator.Element }
    if y.contains({ $0 == nil }) {
        return nil
    } else {
        return y.flatMap{ $0 }   // Swift 1.2 : y.map{ $0! }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Changed according to your edit

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I oversimplified my example. While that works for returning a Bool, my actual end-goal is to get either the casted type or an error, and I don't see a way to do that by specializing the function for SequenceTypes since I still wouldn't be able cast the result. I'll update my sample code to make that more clear.

Comment: @RayLillywhite I can't understand why this shouldn't work, I updated my answer. Maybe your problem is still too simplified?

Comment: Oh, sorry, there was a bad return type in the function signature. The problem is that I need to be able to return the casted value if the conditional downcast succeeds.